# Difference between <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/> and <xsl:apply-templates />

Tags: xslt

When using XSL what is the difference between

`<xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>`

and

`<xsl:apply-templates />`

The former does not appear to bring in any text after a child element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Correct. `"*"` or `"./*"` selects the child elements of the context node. But `"node()"` or `"./node()"` selects all the children including elements, text nodes, comments, and processing instructions. The default for xsl:apply-templates is select="node()".

Comment: Wondering about this myself. +1

Comment: I am learning `xpath` and getting stuck in some small points. Now I can put those in SO as a question. But I think those are not welcome in SO. So may I get a kind of personal help from you for the same ?

Comment: No. Use the process. Ask a question on SO like everyone else. Just because someone gives time to answer questions here doesn't mean they're prepared to answer direct questions from strangers. You forget that when we answer here, we have selected the questions which (a) we find interesting, (b) we know how to answer, and (c) arrive at a moment that happens to be convenient.